Strange shell tab completion behaviour
I'm using the argparse Python module in a script that looks like this:
import argparse

def get_info(line: str) -> tuple:
    print(line.split("|"))
    
def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    p.add_argument("-f", "--file")
    p.add_argument("-d", "--directory")
    p.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                    default="stdout",
                    required=False)
                    
    args = p.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When I try to run it like this:
python script.py path/to/my/

and then press tab, it shows me the list of possible files and directories; no problem here, that's all fine
However, if I try to run it with the -f flag:
python script.py -f path/to/my/

and then press tab, it automatically completes it with a directory, if there are more directories, it lists them, but it completely ignores the files and I have no idea why.
If I run it with a double-dash (--file):
python script.py --file path/to/my/

then it works fine again.
Is it a shell problem or Python problem?

That's all happening before the Python executable or specific script even gets called, so it's not a Python problem.

Your shell has a specific bash readline completion profile that's been set that happens to cause this interference, check using complete -p and see which list might cause it, or just remove all of it by complete -r and see if that issue is resolved. Relevant thread on auto-completion profiles.

As @metatoaster said, I removed all custom completion entries with complete -r, I made a backup first with complete -p > backup.sh and that seems to have solved the issue! Thank you all very much!

Note that complete -r only applies to the current shell session. You will need to figure out exactly which one to disable and make whatever changes required to your .bashrc or equivalent.
